# Call a function on click of home button in ios

Tags: ios, background

I have a function which logs some strings in iOS. On the click of the home button I need to call the same function I don't want to use `AppDelegate` delegate method since Iam building static library instead I will use NSNotification center  this my code . What's happening with me is when I click the Home Button the  function  `-(void)log` is not executing

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:[self class] selector:@selector(appWillResignActive:) name:UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification object:nil];


+ (void)appWillResignActive:(NSNotification *)notification
{


        ABC * abc = [[ABC alloc]init];
        [abc log];

}


Inside ABC class

-(void)log
{
  NSLog (@"abc called");
}
```

Comment: "*I don't want to use `AppDelegate` delegate method*" Why not, if it ends up being the best way? **Not wanting to** is not a valid reason, especially if it'll get the job done. Would you mind elaborating a little on why you say that?

Comment: @esqew please check the edits

Comment: Is the `appWillResignActive:` method called at all?

Comment: @esqew ya it is called but not logging i have checked it with breakpoints